# OPTIONAL MATCH returns no path for disconnect nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I find weird that using OPTIONAL MATCH nodes that don’t have the expected relationship are not returned as a single node in path.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (:Person) -[:LIKES]- (:Movie) 
UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
UNWIND rels(p) as e 
WITH n 
WHERE HEAD(LABELS(n)) = “Person” 
return COUNT(DISTINCT n)
```

The number of people returned only includes those who liked a movie. By using OPTIONAL I would have expected all people to be returned.
Is there a workaround to this or am I doing some this wrong in the query?

Comment: I should have added that the issue is due to the UNWIND rels()

Comment: UNWIND produces rows, if no rows are produced by the UNWIND it doesn't go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to go about this would be to match to all :People nodes first, then use the OPTIONAL MATCH to match to movies (or, if you want a collection of the movies they liked, use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension)).

If you do need to perform an UNWIND on an empty collection without wiping out the row, use a CASE around some condition to use a single-element list rather than the empty list.

```
MATCH (n:Person)   // match all persons
OPTIONAL MATCH p = (n) -[:LIKES]- (m:Movie) // p and m are the optionals
UNWIND CASE WHEN p is null THEN [null] ELSE nodes(p) END as nodes  // already have n, using a different variable
UNWIND CASE WHEN p is null THEN [null] ELSE rels(p) END as e // forcing a single element list means UNWIND won't wipe out the row
WITH n 
WHERE HEAD(LABELS(n)) = “Person”  // not really needed at all, and bad practice, you don't know the order of the labels on a node
return COUNT(DISTINCT n) // if this is really all you need, just keep the first match and the return of the query (without distinct), don't need anything else
```

Comment: Brilliant! I would never have thought using CASE for this, now it seems so obvious. Indeed I need to use UNWIND to return the starting node together with others.

Comment: Because p cannot be null unless these is no people in the graph, I changed the your proposal with UNWIND CASE WHEN length(p) = 0 THEN [null] ELSE relationships(p) END as e.

Comment: My placement of `p` is different than yours. It's on the OPTIONAL MATCH after we've already matched to `n`, so it can be null when a person does not like a movie.

Comment: Is it because you start with match (n:Person) before the optional match?

Comment: Yes. That ensures `n` will match to all :Person nodes. The OPTIONAL MATCH will not change that, but the variables newly-introduced in that OPTIONAL MATCH (`p` and `m`) will be null if there is no match to that pattern in the graph.